# Timezone issue with stripe billing_cycle_anchor tag

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to to give last day of the month to subscription, so that prorated amount is charged based on subscription created. I am using below code to calculate the month last day:

```
var date = new Date();
var lastDay = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
var monthLastDay = Math.floor(lastDay/1000);
```

I am in IST time zone so I am getting monthLastDay as 1527724800 which is equal to: 05/31/2018 @ 12:00am (UTC)
Above code is working fine with prorated amount, but there is an issue with the subscription.
I am creating subscription on 5/11/2018. So prorated amount is calculating from 5/11/2018 to 5/31/2018. But subscription is created from 5/31/2018.

I want subscription to be scheduled on 6/1/2018. Could anyone help me and point out where I am going wrong.

**NOTE:** I am converting date to UTC time zone to avoid different timezone issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is worth pointing out that the billing anchor should be specified in UTC timezone. If you specify this in your local timezone, it will not work as expected.  So there is no way to renew subs according to your customer's or your own timezone.

We specified it for our customers in NZDT, on the 1st of March, but Stripe turned this into the 28th of Feb (GMT) and as a result subsequent invoices were created with the 28th of the month as anchor.

Whether you use moment or not has no bearing on this issue, it would be helpful if Stripe documented this a bit better and advised what timezone to use.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend that you use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) instead of directly dealing with `Date`. If you want to get the first day of the next month, you can get that very easily using moment:

```
var nextMonthFirstDay = moment().utc().add(1,"month").startOf("month");
```

And if you need the last day of the current month, it is:

```
var thisMonthLastDay = moment().utc().endOf("month");
```

You can see an example here:

```js
var thisMonthLastDay = moment().utc().endOf("month");
console.log(thisMonthLastDay.toString())
console.log(thisMonthLastDay.unix())

var nextMonthFirstDay = moment().utc().add(1,"month").startOf("month");
console.log(nextMonthFirstDay.toString())
console.log(nextMonthFirstDay.unix())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer with DayJS rather than MomentJS, And accounting for the timezone issue somewhat in Adam's response**

According to the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle) you must set the "billing_cycle_anchor" flag to a **UTC** unix timestamp. Another method is to use the trial period to anchor to a new billing cycle and invoice your proration charge manually.

I do this in my own application with [DayJS](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/installation) (note that  using [moment.js that is discouraged by the creators](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)). Rough example below using Express accounting for some timezone variable. So you can do something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');
const timezone = require('dayjs/plugin/timezone');
// Require Stripe
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe(config.STRIPE_SK);

dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

router.post('/subscribe/general/', async (req, res) => {
const stripePrice = "Some_Price_Id"
const UserData = ["Some Array Of Customer Data"]

//DayJS stuff
const timezone = "Europe/London";
const currentDay = dayjs(timezone);
const endOfMonth = dayjs(currentDay).endOf('month');
const startOfNextMonth = dayjs(endOfMonth).add(1, 'day'); 
const convertToUnix = dayjs(startOfNextMonth).unix();


//Create the Subscription
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(
    {
      default_payment_method: UserData.paymentMethod.id,
      customer: UserData.StripeCustomerId,
      billing_cycle_anchor: convertToUnix, // unix timestamp
      items: [
        {
          price: stripePrice,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      idempotencyKey: `${
       UserData._id + convertToUnix
      }_sub`,
    },
  );


**// Continue On With Whatever Your application is doing.**
```

I've unpacked the DayJS variables so you can see what's going on but you can definitely make the time calculation more compact.