# Stripe: Prorated amount using billing_cycle_anchor

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using billing_cycle_anchor when creating a subscription. I have a requirement where I need to charge from the day of payment to last of the month. And then from 1st of every month.
I am using code shown below:

```
var date = new Date();
var lastDay = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
var monthLastDay = Math.floor(lastDay/1000);

let subscription = {
    metadata: metadata,
    billing_cycle_anchor: monthLastDay
};
```

Using above below is what is happening:

1. Prorated amount is charged from May 16 to May 31st
2. Subscription is created from May 31 – Jun 30.
   But I want subscription to be created from June 1.

**EDIT:**

Right now time which is being calculated is:
1527724800
which is equivalent to:
05/31/2018 @ 12:00am (UTC)

Please let me know possible solution.

Comment: Just change `billing_cycle_anchor` to be a few hours later so that it charges in the middle of the 1st in UTC like at 10am or 12pm

Comment: But it is 10 digit timestamp right? Can you provide me code for doing that?

Comment: It is a unix timestamp yes. You would do what you do in your code but also set the exact time to be 10 am in UTC instead of the default which is likely 12am UTC.

Comment: I have updated code to `var lastDay = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0, 10);`. But still I got same results on subscription.

Comment: Take the time to debug this on your end I think by taking the timestamp and checking the date it corresponds to with something like https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ My guess is that it is still a day in the past and would be easy to debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone issue with stripe billing\_cycle\_anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288310/timezone-issue-with-stripe-billing-cycle-anchor-tag)